# Finding character patterns in a dictionary .txt file

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to scan through a dictionary and identify which words in said dictionary follow a certain order of letters in Java. For example, pattern `i`, `n`, and `g`, would include flail **ing**, while permitting any of the other 23 letters to separate `i`, `n`, and `g`, but still have to be in the same order (i.e. a word named `isong` would still qualify, because it follows `i`, `n`, *THEN* `g`

but not "align" because it follows "i", "g", then "n"). For reference, "words.txt" is the dictionary file without spaces. In addition, my professor disallowed the use of Regex. What I'm trying to do is fix findWords and read the file, and put all the words into a String array called "words" in `readDictionary`. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SearchWords {

public static void main (String[] argv)
{
mainTest ();
}


static void mainTest ()
{
  String[] words = WordTool.getDictionary ();
  char[] inputset = {'i', 'n', 'g'};
  findWords (words, inputset);
}

static void findWords (String[] words, char[] inputset)
{
    String[] w = words;
    char[] ing = inputset;
}
class WordTool {

static String[] getDictionary ()
{
    return getDictionary ("words.txt");
}

static String[] getDictionary (String fileName)
{
    String[] words = readDictionary (fileName);
    String[] scrubbedWords = scrub (words);
    return scrubbedWords;  
}

static String[] readDictionary (String fileName)
{
    String[] words = null;
    LinkedList<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();

    try 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new FileReader (fileName));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) 
        {
    // At each step, get the next word and place in list.
    String s = scanner.next();
    stringList.addLast (s);
    }

    // Now that size is known, make an array.
    words = new String [stringList.size()];
    Iterator<String> iter = stringList.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext()) 
        {
    words[i] = iter.next();
    i ++;
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(WordTool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return words;
}


static String[] scrub (String[] words)
{
    // Remove words with caps, and single-letter words
    int badWords = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() <= 1) {
            badWords ++;
            words[i] = null;
        }
        else if ( Character.isUpperCase (words[i].charAt(0)) ) {
            badWords ++;
            words[i] = null;
        }
    }

// Make space for the good words.
    String[] realWords = new String [words.length - badWords];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<realWords.length; i++) {
        while (words[j] == null) {
            j ++;
        }
        realWords[i] = words[j];
        j ++;
    }

    return realWords;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the java regular expression to help you to do that.
Simply build a pattern as following to search the if the input string have 'i','n' and 'g' in sequence:

`.*i.*n.*g.*`

'.' in regular expression means any characters and '*' means 0 to infinity occurrence

following code snaps for your reference to use java regex

```
public boolean matchPattern(String pattern, String inputString){
    Pattern pattern = 
                Pattern.compile(pattern);

                Matcher matcher = 
                pattern.matcher(inputString);

                boolean found = false;
                while (matcher.find()) {
                   return true;
                }

      return false;
}
```

to use this method, just call it:

```
   boolean foundIng = matchPattern(".*i.*n.*g.*" , "sample Input String ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

static void findWords (String[] inputWords, char[] inputset)
{
    ArrayList[] words = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of words that match the pattern. Lists* are of dynamic length, unlike their cousins, the array, which are fixed length. This one is typecasted to only be able to contain Strings
    char[] ing = inputset; // the pattern

    for (String s : inputWords)
    { // a for-each** loop through inputWords. Incidentally, in your original code, inputWords was called 'words', the same as your resulting list.
        int wi = 0; // index in the 'ing' array that we are up to
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        { // loop through every char in each word...
            if (c == ing[wi])
            { // ... then check if the current character is the next one in the pattern...
                wi++; // ... and if so, proceed to the next character in the pattern to match against
                if (wi == ing.length)
                { // We've run out of characters to check against, so we know that the word matches the pattern
                    words.add(s); // add the word to the list of words that match the pattern
                    break; // break out of the checking loop, so that the first loop proceeds onto the next word in the dictionary
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Do something with your final list of words here
    // String[] wordsList = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]); // Uncomment this line if you want the words list to be an array, instead of a list
}
```

* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html is the oracle javadoc page on ArrayLists
** See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html for more info on the for-each loop